# Как получить дамп образа BIOS с локальной машины

Tags: ассемблер, железо, bios, ram

Понадобилось сделать дамп образа BIOS на ноутбуке. Прочитать его напрямую с флеш-памяти на материнской плате возможным не представляется. Где-то слышал, что при загрузке компьютера, код BIOS считывается из флеша и записывается куда-то в самое начало адресного пространства физической памяти. Может быть, существуют какие-то методы/инструменты, которыми можно считать образ?

Answer (score 2):

Обычно доступен *некоторый* код BIOS: например, video BIOS в диапазоне адресов `0xC0000`–`0xC7FFF`, BIOS материнской платы в диапазоне `0xF0000—0xFFFFF` и т.п. (см. [x86 Memory Map на OSDev Wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86)#ROM_Area)). Но flash-микросхема, хранящая BIOS, чаще всего гораздо больше этого размера (например, 8 MiB), при этом нет стандартных адресов, где он был бы отображён. Поэтому определённо не удастся снять образ всего BIOS таким простым способом.

Не знаю, однако, почему "*Прочитать его напрямую с флеш-памяти на материнской плате возможным не представляется*". Возможно, удастся-таки прочитать его целиком с помощью [flashrom](https://www.flashrom.org/Flashrom).